\lstlistoflistings is empty and no .lol file is generated
Due to (me as inexperienced user) some reasons, the combination of using lstlisting along with tcolorbox isn't working, so I tried to go with minted inside tcolorbox inside the listing environment (but I have to use the listings package, not just listing), which seems to be working. However, both \listoflistings and \lstlistoflisting give only the heading and no content. The main.lol file is not generated.
Here is the ME:
\documentclass[twoside, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{listings}


\newtcolorbox{tbox1}[1][]{
      title = \color{\VARTITLECOLOR}{#1},
      width = \linewidth,
      boxsep = 5mm,
      left=5mm,
      right=5mm,
      size = small,
      fonttitle=\textbf{\color{black}},
      colframe=lime,
      colback=gray!10,
      halign=flush center,
      valign = center,
      arc=0mm,
      % arc is angular,
      % sharp corners=uphill,
      boxrule=0mm,
      leftrule=1mm,
      %rightrule=0mm,
      box align = base,
      detach title,
      enhanced, 
      colbacktitle=dgray,
      overlay={
          \node[rotate=0, minimum width=1cm, anchor=south, yshift= 0cm, xshift=0.5cm] at (frame.west) {\tcbtitle};
      },
}

\addcontentsline{lol}{lstlisting}{\protect\numberline{}A new listing}
\addtocontents{lol}{A new listing}
\begin{listing}[H]
    \begin{tbox1}
    \begin{minted}{python}
        import numpy as np
 
        class LinearNeuron:
            def __init__(self, weights):
                self.weights = weights

            def forward(self, x):
                return np.dot(self.weights, x)
    \end{minted}
    \end {tbox1}
\captionof{lstlisting}{A new listing} % \caption{A new listing} makes no difference
\label{lst:LNU}
\end{listing}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={A new listing}]
    adcd
\end{lstlisting}

The compilation is without error, the code is shown as desired, but the content of LOL is just missing.
BTW if I use the lstlisting instead of listing environment, it's just not working and I'd like to avoid it, if possible. Or if it's easier to fix this way, I need to set the caption of it to be under the code example.

Welcome to TeX.SE, the code does not run, is this deliberate? For instance, it is missing a document environment.

With the shown example there are errors. The first one would be ! undefined control sequence. l.6 \newtcolorbox. But there are several others.

You need to complete your MWE. Your forgot to include the tcolorbox package along with \begin{document} and \end{document}. That managed to cut down the amount of errors to 2, but I must still be missing something since yours compile without any error. It's a bit hard to guess what's missing.

\listofllistings comes from the listing (no s) package.  See page 9 of the listlings manual.  You can also use the newfloat package and \DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=lol,listname=Listings]{listing}.

This shows how to use the newfloat package to produce a \listoflistings.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{listing}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=lol,listname=Listings]{listing}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\let\c@listing\c@lstlisting}% use same counter for listing and lstlisting
\makeatother

%\usepackage{caption}

\newtcolorbox{tbox1}[1][]{
      title = \color{\VARTITLECOLOR}{#1},
      width = \linewidth,
      boxsep = 5mm,
      left=5mm,
      right=5mm,
      size = small,
      fonttitle=\textbf{\color{black}},
      colframe=lime,
      colback=gray!10,
      halign=flush center,
      valign = center,
      arc=0mm,
      % arc is angular,
      % sharp corners=uphill,
      boxrule=0mm,
      leftrule=1mm,
      %rightrule=0mm,
      box align = base,
      detach title,
      %enhanced, 
      colbacktitle=gray,
      overlay={
          \node[rotate=0, minimum width=1cm, anchor=south, yshift= 0cm, xshift=0.5cm] at (frame.west) {\tcbtitle};
      },
}
\begin{document}
\listoflistings
%\addcontentsline{lol}{lstlisting}{\protect\numberline{}A new listing}
%\addtocontents{lol}{A new listing}
\begin{listing}[h]
    \begin{tbox1}
      \begin{lstlisting}
        test1
      \end{lstlisting}
    \end {tbox1}
\caption{A new listing}
%\captionof{lstlisting}{A new listing}
\label{lst:LNU}
\end{listing}

\begin{lstlisting}[float=h,caption={A new listing}]
    test2
\end{lstlisting}
\arabic{lstlisting}

\end{document}


The issue was caused by the package multitoc. I disabled that and it started to work, but I can't use more columns in lof and lot, which is ok for me. Hope it will help somebody.

This is partly why we're so annoying about a MWE.  multitoc is nowhere in your question, so no one would have been able to help you.  It's possible we could make it work the way you'd like, but you have to give us enough code to know what you're doing.

Old versions of multitoc indeed disabled all auxiliary files but toc, lof, lot. But with current version 2.02 this does not happen any longer. So if this really was the source (not shown in the question) an update should solve it. But because there isn't a MWE in the question nor here in the answer, this is only a guess and cannot be verified (and therefore not only the question but more or less also the answer is unfortunately not very useful).
